# Can't save more than 2 Elements in ArrayList to MySQL with SpringBoot?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, arraylist

I can't save more than 2 Elements in ArrayList to MySQL with SpringBoot. When i make a post request (Postman or with Alamofire) with one object in array i get status code 200 otherwise I get status code 500 and this error message in springboot console:

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`quran-pro-core`.`surah`, CONSTRAINT `FKibuxjpjiwpq46220g7sn7y1q` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `reciter` (`documentid`))

These are my classes:

```
@RestController
public class ReciterController {

     @Autowired
     private ReciterService reciterService;

     @PostMapping("/reciters")
     public String saveReciter(@RequestBody Reciter reciter) {
     reciterService.saveReciter(reciter);
     return "SUCCESS";
   }
}

@Service
public class ReciterService {

     @Autowired
     private ReciterRepostitory reciterRepository;

     public void saveReciter(Reciter reciter) {
     reciterRepository.save(reciter);
     }
}

@Entity
public class Reciter {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long documentID;

     @Column
     private String name;
     @Column
     private String image;
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<Surah> surahs;

     // Constructor and getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Surah {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;

     @Column
     private String name;
     @Column
     private int number;

     // Constructor and getters and setters

}
```

This body works:

```
{
"name": "reciter1",
"image": "/reciter1/image.png",
"surahs": [
         {
            "name": "LOLll",
            "number": 0
        }

]
}
```

and this doesn't:

```
{
"name": "reciter1",
"image": "/reciter1/image.png",
"surahs": [
         {
            "name": "LOLll",
            "number": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "test2",
            "number": 1
        }
]
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Your OneToMany mapping makes no sense. Here's how you map a unidirectional OneToMany asociation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-unidirectional. And here's how you map a bidirectional one: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: when i use the bidirectional and i do a post request i get status code 200 but when i get the reciters i get an empty array on surahs

Answer (score 0):

You `ManyToOne` configuration is not correct, the `mappedBy` element must be used to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that is the owner of the relationship

1. First suggestion, use bidirectional relation :

```java
public class Reciter {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long documentID;

     @Column
     private String name;
     @Column
     private String image;
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="reciter", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<Surah> surahs;

     // Constructor and getters and setters

}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Surah {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;

     @Column
     private String name;
     @Column
     private int number;

     @ManyToOne
    private Reciter reciter;
}
```

2. or use Unidirectional relation :

```java
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<Surah> surahs;
```

Comment: when i use the bidirectional and i do a post request i get status code 200 but when i get the reciters i get an empty array on surahs

Comment: your `saveReciter()` is not complete, you need to save surahs too, for each surah do `surah.setReciter(reciter)` and save them using a specific repository for surahs.

Comment: I#m new to sql and java i don't know how to do it :( Can you help me